# Glassfish application didn't inject service class with entityManager

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, dependency-injection, glassfish, cdi

I have a application which is build with Maven and has the following module structure

```
<modules>
        <module>ProjectMonkeybutler-ear</module>
        <module>ProjectMonkeybutler-ejb</module>
        <module>ProjectMonkeybutler-web</module>
        <module>ProjectMonkeybutler-persistence</module>
 </modules>
```

I would like to @Inject my BoothService class which has an EntityManager to persist my objects. The BoothService class is always null and never injected by the application server (GF 4.0).

```
package com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.service;

import com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Booth;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
@Named("BoothService")
public class BoothService  implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BoothService.class.getName());

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public BoothService() {

        if(entityManager == null){
            LOGGER.info("EntityManger is null");
        }
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
       return entityManager;
    }

    public void persist(final Booth entity) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Persist {0}", entity);
        this.getEntityManager().persist(entity);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Persisted");

    }

}
```

My Controller class in the web project:

```
package com.skb.monkeybutler.web;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@SessionScoped
@Named
public class CompanyRegistrationController implements Serializable {


    @Inject
    private @Named("BoothService") BoothService bs;

        public CompanyRegistrationController() {
            if(bs == null){ LOGGER.info("BoothService is null"); } 
    }
}
```

My persistence xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.skb_ProjectMonkeybutler-persistence_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/jeedb</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Companydata</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.CompanyEquipment</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Studycourse</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Booth</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Setuptimeslot</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Company</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Volunteer</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Servicepackage</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Billingaddress</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Equipment</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Faculty</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Team</class>
    <class>com.skb.monkeybutler.persistence.entity.Vacancy</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="none"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
      <!--  turn on fine logging: -->
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface out of `BoothService` class. CDI will only inject interfaces from EJB (the BoothService is an EJB)

Answer (score 0):

Injected fields will be null in the constructor. They are injected after object is created. Define method with `@PostConstruct` annotation and test injected fields there.
You could also try to inject `BoothService` with the `@EJB` annotation.